# How to use simple pay api of paypal for money transfer using CURL

Tags: php, paypal

I want to transfer fund from one paypal account to another for this i have got simple pay api of adaptive but i want to use this api using curl.

```
curl https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/Pay \
  -s \
  --insecure \
  -H "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID: api_username" \
  -H "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD: api_password" \
  -H "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE: api_signature" \
  -H "X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT: NV" \
  -H "X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT: NV" \
  -H "X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID: app_id" \
  -d actionType=PAY \
  -d senderEmail=sender@domain \
  -d cancelUrl=http://your_cancel_url \
  -d currencyCode=USD \
  -d receiverList.receiver(0).email=receiver@domain \
  -d receiverList.receiver(0).amount=100.00 \
  -d requestEnvelope.errorLanguage=en_US \
  -d returnUrl=http://your_return_url
```

I just need a trick to use this in curl and make payment by sending data to paypal and receive in json